# Unable to reason why the code is not behaving as expected in a simple while loop

Tags: python, python-2.7, while-loop, mergesort

I am trying to implement the merge-sort algorithm in python here. I am pasting the code (with the prints to trace the flow) and the output of the same. As you can see, everything works correctly up until the final merge operation.

```
def mergesort(alist):
if(len(alist) == 1):
    return alist
else:
    mid = len(alist)/2
    leftHalf = mergesort(alist[:mid])
    rightHalf = mergesort(alist[mid:])

    i, j, k = 0, 0, 0 #i= leftHalf counter, j= rightHalf counter, k= alist counter

    while i < len(leftHalf) and j < len(rightHalf):
        if(leftHalf[i] < rightHalf[j]):
            alist[k] = leftHalf[j]
            i += 1; k += 1
        else:
            alist[k] = rightHalf[j]
            j += 1; k += 1
        print "i=", i, "j=", j, "k=",k
    print "quit the loop"

    if(i<j):    #it means j has proceeded ahead in its righthalf
        remaining = leftHalf
        r = i
    else:
        remaining = rightHalf
        r = j

    print remaining
    print "k =",k
    while (r < len(remaining)):
        alist[k] = remaining[r]
        r += 1; k += 1

    print "i =", i , ";j = ", j,";k = ", k
    print "alist sorted =", alist
    print "*********"
    return alist

alist = [3,9,6,12,4,5]
mergesort(alist)
print alist
```

Following is the trace for the input `alist = [3,9,6,12,4,5]`

[image: Tracing]

The `while` condition that says `while i < len(leftHalf) and j < len(rightHalf):` must allow `6` to be copied from `leftHalf[1]` to `alist[3]`, right? I don't see this happening.

If someone could explain why this is failing, it'll put me out of my misery :)

Comment: I'm puzzled. Isn't `[3,4,5,9,9,12]` a correct result?

Comment: It is skipping `6` there. Can't meddle with the elements like that :D

Comment: I'm pretty sure this code should crash. You should use integer division (`//`) when calculating `mid`

Comment: Oh I didn't know about the `//` integer division thing. It actually works fine without it too. I'll make that correction though. That's how it should be. Thanks :)

Comment: Hmm.. perhaps Python 2 is forgiving, because my Python 3 crashes on that.

Comment: Yea, I use Python 2.7.

Comment: Yeah, I can see that from the `print` statements. In python3 it's `print()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mistake is here

```
if(leftHalf[i] < rightHalf[j]):
    alist[k] = leftHalf[j]
    i += 1; k += 1
else:
    alist[k] = rightHalf[j]
    j += 1; k += 1
```

you need not `leftHalf[j]`, but `leftHalf[i]` in `alist[k] = leftHalf[j]`.